# Ubuntu 20.04 VM - Desktop hangs shortly after fresh install

Tags: boot, 20.04, crash

To clarify - The installation seems to work, and you eventually get the desktop and all the icons.  You have about 30 seconds before it becomes completely unresponsive.  And when you reboot, you just get a flashing cursor.  I've been googling it for about 5 hours now, you can't enter any keyboard commands (ctrl+alt+f3 etc) so that won't help.  VT-x is enabled in the bios and working as far as I'm aware.  No HyperV options enabled.

If a log would be useful, just let me know where to find it and I'll paste it in.